# Is there a way to automate the entry of external testers email info for Testflight?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I would like to integrate signup of External Testflight users with an existing website we have that collects interested beta test users. I see that I can export any new signups once and a while and manually upload a CSV of their emails to testflight. This works somewhat well. But this is the digital age :) is there an API or tool like iTMSTransporter that will automate this process for me? Is everyone else just  typing them in as they go or uploading CSV files once and a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch an instance of `boarding` on heroku.  It's part of the fastlane toolchain.

https://github.com/fastlane/boarding

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer to my question was "no."

But the longer answer is to go use Ruby or something similar and a web test tool such as Capybara ( http://jnicklas.github.io/capybara/ ) to automate what a user would do on the actual iTunes connect website but in a scripting language.